# Smooth full page scrolling with mouse wheel

Tags: angular, typescript

I do smooth full page scrolling with the mouse wheel.

But **scrollIntoView** function doesn't work inside **@HostListener('wheel', ['$event'])**.

In app.component.html file:

```
<div #page *ngFor="let page of [0,1,2,3,4]" [class]="'vh-100 p-3 bg-' + (page + 1)">
  <h3 class="text-white">Page {{page + 1}}</h3>
  <div class="page-content">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <p>beatae esse velit laudantium nam eligendi possimus</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav">
  <button #prev class="btn btn-sm btn-light me-1" (click)="clickPrev()">prev</button>
  <button #next class="btn btn-sm btn-light" (click)="clickNext()">next</button>
</div>
```

In app.component.ts file:

```
  @ViewChildren('page') pages: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  @ViewChild('prev') prev: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('next') next: ElementRef;

  idlePeriod = 100;
  animationDuration = 1000;
  lastAnimation = 0;
  index = 0;

  togglePageContent(index, state) {
    if (state === 'show') {
      this.pages.toArray()[index].nativeElement.querySelector('.page-content')
        .classList.add('show');
    } else {
      this.pages.toArray()[index].nativeElement.querySelector('.page-content')
        .classList.remove('show');
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.togglePageContent(0, 'show');
  }

  clickPrev() {
    if (this.index < 1) return;
    this.togglePageContent(this.index, 'hide');
    this.index--;
    this.pages.forEach((page, i) => {
      if (i === this.index) {
        this.togglePageContent(i, 'show');
        page.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    });
  }

  clickNext() {
    if (this.index > 3) return;
    this.togglePageContent(this.index, 'hide');
    this.index++;
    this.pages.forEach((page, i) => {
      if (i === this.index) {
        this.togglePageContent(i, 'show');
        page.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      }
    });
  }

  @HostListener('wheel', ['$event'])
  onMouseWheel(event) {
    var delta = 0;
    if (event['wheelDelta']) {
      delta = event['wheelDelta'];
    }
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if ( timeNow - this.lastAnimation < this.idlePeriod + this.animationDuration ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
    }

    if (delta < 0) {
      this.next.nativeElement.click();
      // this.pages.toArray()[this.index + 1].nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
    } else {
      this.prev.nativeElement.click();
      // this.pages.toArray()[this.index - 1].nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
    }

    this.lastAnimation = timeNow;
```

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-fullpage-easily?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I have another example a bit like javascript and it works with **document.addEventListener('wheel', (event: WheelEvent) => {})"**

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-fullpage-smooth-with-mousewheel?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

How can **ScrollIntoView** work inside **@HostListener('wheel', ['$event'])**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@HostListener` is working normally.
The only thing that making the awkward scrolling effect is the css.

- The 1st thing is to wrap the button and content in a parent div with 100vh
- The 2nd thing is make the content position relative to its original position

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-fullpage-easily-rdox29?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<div class="vh-100 overflow-hidden">
  <div #page *ngFor="let page of [0,1,2,3,4]" [class]="'vh-100 p-3 position-relative bg-' + (page + 1)">
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If outside the "parent" tag I have extra content. Is there a way to prevent this error from happening?

Comment: You can tune the parent height and have other content alongside with the parent. updated stackblitz, you can have a look